# How do I prevent the solve() function in R from returning a trivial solution?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to use `solve()` in R to find a solution for a 10x10 matrix. Specifically, I am looking for x in Ax=b where b is a ten dimensional 0 vector. When I input `solve(A, rep(0,10))`, R returns the trivial solution, namely `rep(0,10)`. I also checked -- `det(A)` is indeed not equal to `0` and thus not singular.

So how can I stop R from returning this result?

Answer (score 1):

Premultiplying both sides of the equation by the inverse of A gives x=A^{-1}b, i.e. on the right hand side we have a zero vector because b is a zero vector. So, that is the only solution.

Comment: Nice. So an answer to "how can I stop R from returning this result?" in this case would be: take a vector b which is not zero ;-).